# Are autonomous transactions implemented in PostgreSQL v15?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I searched the official docs with no luck, but I found a few answers here on DBA referring to them in PG after introducing procedures. Are autonomous transactions implemented in PostgreSQL v15? Thank you.

Comment: No, they are not available

Comment: What is the hold?